Where is the following verse about guru found?

Ekakshara pradataram gurur iti vidhyate.

(Even if someone teaches one letter, He is to be considered a Guru.)
where is that verse found?(Not from Chanakya Neeti)

Ekakshara usually refers to OM which will change the meaning of the verse.

But where is it found?

I'm not aware. May I ask where did you hear it?

A Vidwan ji told me..he could not tell which smriti it is

Ok. To support the fact that ekakshara means just one syllable the way you've specified means we might need another word or two there to explicity state that. The way it's written implies Om. Though that's not what you're asking, it's quite important to ensure what that verse is conveying.

Sir i think it means "a person who teaches even 1 letter is to be considered a guru"

Here are some more variants. Although I think the context is quite different from what you are looking for.

Vidyārṇavatantra chapter 2:


guruṃ mohādanāvṛtya nirmartsya vīrapūruṣān |
vikalpya kulaśāstrāṇi bhavanti brahmarākṣasāḥ || 2-27 ||
ekākṣarapradātāraṃ yo guruṃ naiva manyate |
śunāṃ yoniśataṃ gatvā caṇḍālatvamavāpnuyāt || 2-28 ||
guruṃ prakāśayeddhīmān mantraṃ naiva prakāśayet |
aprakāśaprakāśābhyāṃ kṣīyate sampadāyuṣī || 2-29 ||


Merutantra chapter 10:


tīrthayātrādigamanaṃ kaulikastu vivarjayet ||
ekākṣarapradātāraṃ yo guruṃ cāvamanyate || 611 ||
sa śvayoniśataṃ gatvā cāṇḍālatvamavāpnuyāt || ekasya
hananātkṣemaṃ bahūnāṃ cecchubhā gatiḥ || 612 ||


Tantracintāmaṇi chapter 12


taccheṣamiti saṃciṃtya grāhyaṃ tasyājñayāmudā |
ekākṣarapradātāraṃ yo guruṃtvavamanyate ||
saśca yoniṃ śataṃ gatvā cāṇḍālatvamavāpnuyāt |
guraumanuṣyabuddhiṃ ca maṃtrevākṣarasemuniṃ ||

All texts can be found at Muktabodha library. You might find more texts there.

Though the first phrase of the following sloka does not match exactly to OP's phrase, however, I would like to go ahead and answer this post. Refer Cāṇakya-nīti-darpaṇa [13.20].

एकाक्षरप्रदातारं यो गुरुं नाभिवन्दते ।
श्वानयोनिशतं गत्वा चाण्डालेष्वभिजायते ॥

ekākṣara-pradātāraṁ yo guruṁ nābhivandate |
śvāna-yoni-śataṁ gatvā cāṇḍāleṣv abhijāyate ||

One who does not respect a guru, who has taught [even] a single syllable, 
will undergo one hundred births as a dog and then be born among cāṇḍālas. 

-Cāṇakya-nīti-darpaṇa: 13.20


Beware: The same sloka [13.20] from Cāṇakya-nīti-darpaṇa also appears in Atri Smriti(अत्रि स्मृति) [sloka-10]
Nevertheless, I am still looking around for the sloka which should be OP's exact match.
Good Luck!
